# Add element from excel range Selenium

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-chromedriver

How to add element from excel range?

`bot.findelementbypartiallinktext(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").value).click`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is showing the first match it founds. If you want you can loop through all the links.

```
Sub ByPartialLinkText()
    
    '................
    
    Dim ResultLinks As Selenium.WebElements
    
    Set ResultLinks = bot.FindElementsByPartialLinkText(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").value)
    If ResultLinks.Count > 0 Then
        ResultLinks(1).Click
    End If
        
    '................
End Sub
```

Comment: Run-time error '-21462233080 (80131508)' Indew was outside the bounds of the array @elio fernandes

Comment: `If ResultLinks.Count = 0 Then` looks wrong, should be `If ResultLinks.Count <> 0 Then`.

Comment: @Raymond Wu, you are right! I was testing if no links were found and forgot to correct the if statement. Thanks. Code updated.

Comment: @ElioFernandes it seems like OP got the error based on your original code so it means `ResultLinks.Count` was 0. This probably hints that the element OP is looking for either doesn't exist or it is dynamically loaded and requires more time for the element to be loaded.

Comment: @Raymond Wu, he only put one line of code. Maybe he should some more code.  He didn't complain about the loading time. Let's wait and see what he says.

Comment: Thank you So much @RaymondWu & Elio Fernandes works perfect

Comment: @JacksonJerold Since Elio's answer resolves your issue, please click the tick beside the answer to accept it.